# Type parameters constraints for instances of typeclasses with kind * -> *

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose I have `Heap a` type where `Heap` is type constructor of kind `* -> *`. Many basic operations on heap require the `a` type to be an instance of `Ord` type class.

```
data Heap a = ...

findMin :: Ord a => Heap a -> a
deleteMin :: Ord a => Heap a -> Heap a
```

I want to declare my `Heap` type as an instance of `Foldable` type class as soon as `a` type parameter is an instance of `Ord` type class (it will be easy to express via `findMin` and `deleteMin` functions).

This kind of relation can be easely expressed when we dealing with type classes that require type of kind `*`, like `Show`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Heap a) where
    show h = ...
```

But I have problems with declaration of `Foldable`:

```
instance Foldable Heap where
    -- Ouch, there is no `a` type parameter to put the constraint on!
    foldr f z h = ...
```

Is it possible to put constraint on `a` type parameter in such instance declaration?

Comment: Have a look at [this stuff](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127). They're doing something similar with monads.

Comment: Thank you very much for link, `ConstraintKind` is _really_ interesting stuff!

Comment: Btw, does `findMin` really require an `Ord` instance?

Comment: Some implementations (like the slow list-based one I showed below) don't require `Ord` constraint on `findMin`, but some of them (like the SkewBinominalHeap described by Okasaki) require that constraint. I suppose in real life `Heap` should be a type class with the `Ord` constraint on `findMin`.

Answer (score 19):

In general, no, when the type constructor itself is given the instance, there's no way to constrain the types it's applied to. Mostly this is a good thing, since it ensures that e.g. `Functor` instances are truly agnostic about their element type, which helps keep nice and predictable behavior nice and predictable.

Sometimes it's an annoyance instead, and the most common example is indeed needing an `Ord` constraint for a sorted data structure that could otherwise be a nice, well-behaved instance.

There are some experimental techniques involving stuff like constraint kinds, but in your specific case there's already a viable solution. If you look at the definition of `Foldable`, it says that only `foldMap` or `foldr` need to be implemented, so we'll consider those. Note the types:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldr :: (Foldable t) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

In both cases, the type with a `Foldable` instance only appears once, as an argument to the function. Because of this, you can [use GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt) with an `Ord` constraint:

```
data Heap a where
    Heap :: (Ord a) => ...
```

By doing this, you'll need an `Ord` instance any time you *create* a `Heap` value, even an empty heap; but when you *receive* a `Heap` value, pattern matching on it will bring the `Ord` instance back into scope--even inside the `Foldable` instance!

Note that this doesn't help in many other situations:

```
fmap :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here we can get an `Ord` instance on `a`, but we'd also need one for `b`, which isn't possible.

```
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

Here we need to provide an `Ord` instance as well.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working, I've prepared small sample how to do that here: http://ideone.com/HWl7H.

It looks strange for me, but we can't just use constraints in type declaration like this: `newtype Ord a => ListHeap a = LH [a]`.

This just doesn't work with `Foldable` instance. We really have to use GADTs extension with pattern matching.

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @roman-kashitsyn: Yeah, there is/was a syntax like that for regular data types, but it didn't do the same thing and was a completely useless misfeature and will probably be removed from the language standard eventually (unless it already was and I've forgotten).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `keys` library on Hackage. Check if its `FoldableWithKey` type class is what you need.