# Typeclass instances using methods with constrained types

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

First of all let me apologize, yet I simply couldn't find the answer to my
question although I'm pretty sure that this has been asked before. Now:

I would like to write `Functor` and `Monad` instances for a binary (search)
tree. More precisely, some of the functions like `insert` or `merge` require
instances of `Ord`, e.g.:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
insert :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
merge  :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

Consequently, the following code doesn't compile:

```
instance Monad Tree where
  {- ... -}
  Empty >>= f        = Empty
  (Node v l r) >>= f = merge (f v) (merge newL newR)
                       where newL = l >>= f
                             newR = r >>= f

-- No instance for (Ord b) arising from a use of `merge'...
```

As I didn't know any better, I've tried declaring the `Ord` constraint on the
ADT using `DatatypeContexts` but that's deprecated and didn't work anyway. Other
extensions like `FlexibleInstances` etc. all seemed useful until I realized they
really meant something else.

So, is there a way and how would I go about it? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Meanwhile I found this useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499152/271678), but it appears as if doing this kind of stuff for typeclasses like `Functor` is still an issue.

Comment: You might this helpful http://www.ittc.ku.edu/csdl/fpg/files/Sculthorpe-13-ConstrainedMonad.pdf

Comment: The short answer is that it's not really possible to do with the default `Monad` and `Functor` type-classes. The constraint cannot hold because in any generic, monadic computation you can simply do `return <some non-Ord value>`.

Comment: @JonathanFischoff Thanks a lot, that paper is well worth reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways you can do this, but none of them are completely clean.

The key term you should look up is "restricted monad".

Here's one example with the [`rmonad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad) package (which I wrote).

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, TypeFamilies, GADTs,
             FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Control.RMonad.Prelude
import Data.Suitable


data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
insert :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Tree a
insert = undefined
merge  :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a
merge = undefined

data instance Constraints Tree a where
    TreeConstraints :: Ord a => Constraints Tree a

instance Ord a => Suitable Tree a where
  constraints = TreeConstraints


instance RFunctor Tree where
  fmap f Empty = Empty
  fmap f (Node v l r) = Node (f v) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)    


instance RMonad Tree where
  {- ... -}
  Empty >>= f        = Empty
  (Node v l r) >>= f = withResConstraints $ \TreeConstraints ->
        merge (f v) (merge newL newR)
           where newL = l >>= f
                 newR = r >>= f
```

See the general documentation for the package [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8.0.2/docs/Control-RMonad.html).

Note that `RMonad` is a different type class to `Monad`. If you want to have a real `Monad` instance you can use [`AsMonad Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rmonad-0.8.0.2/docs/Control-RMonad-AsMonad.html).

Comment: At first glance, the normalization approach explained in the paper mentioned by Jonathan seems a bit "easier" to me, but admittedly the authors themselves postulate that their approach resembles only a minor difference to `rmonad`. Guess it'll take some time for me to stomach all this. Thanks a lot so far!