# Constraints for instances of typeclasses not mentioning the constrained type variable

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Let's say we're writing a simple bitset that uses a field of type `c` (think `Word`) to signify the presence of different values of type `a`:

```hs
data BitSet c a = BitSet c
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Data, Typeable, Generic, NFData)

isSet :: (Bits c, Enum a) => a -> BitSet c a -> Bool
isSet e (BitSet c) = testBit c $ fromEnum e
```

`a` is assumed to be `Enum` so that it could be converted to an integer corresponding to the bit index.

Let's now try writing a `Foldable` instance for `BitSet c`, starting with the following:

```hs
instance FiniteBits c => Foldable (BitSet c) where
    foldr f b0 (BitSet c) = foldr f b0 list
        where (list :: [a]) = toEnum <$> filter (testBit c) [0..finiteBitSize c - 1]
```

But this won't work: it doesn't have the constraint that `a` should satisfy `Enum a`, and I don't see any way to provide it (and I have a gut feel that it doesn't make much sense from more theoretical point of view if `a` isn't listed in the instance declaration, but that's probably another story).

The most voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497542/type-parameters-constraints-for-instances-of-typeclasses-with-kind) suggests that using GADTs might help, but GADTs have their own shortcomings:

1. One would need to use standalone deriving, which gets particularly ugly for Data and Typeable, and, what's worse,
2. GADTs seem to break derivation of Generic for this type at all.

Is there any other way to write a `Foldable` instance while still keeping autoderived Generic instance?

Comment: are you sure you want `data BitSet c a = BitSet c` and not `data BitSet c a = BitSet a`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe yep, `c` defines the underlying representation and `a` is there to just allow distinguishing between `BitSet`s storing different values on type level.

Comment: If "a is assumed to be Enum so that it could be converted to an integer", then what you really want is to simply store an integer. The Foldable instance doesn't really make sense, precisely because you need a constraint on the 'contained' type to make sense of it. If you change your type to `data BitSet c = BitSet Integer` then it should be apparent why Foldable doesn't make sense - you have no tyvar to fold over. Furthermore, your type should be abstract, and as such, `Data` and `Generic` instances (at least the derived ones) for it don't make sense as they allow you to break the abstraction.

Comment: @user2407038 Let's fix `c = Word` for clariy (assuming `Word` is big enough to hold bits for all possible values of `a`), then `BitSet Word a`  is isomorphic to `Data.Set a` (for some `a`), and `Data.Set` is indeed `Foldable`. The only reason why an additional constraint for `a` is there is due to the implementation details, namely, the way the values of `a` are recovered from the internal representation. Doesn't reasoning like this make sense?

Comment: @0xd34df00d If you pack the `Enum` instance into the type, and you only use `toEnum` (from the Enum class) this is morally the same as `exists x . (x, x -> Integer)` which is isomorphic to `Integer`. But you are correct, it is just an implementation detail, and you should be free to implement it however you like. Replace `a` with `Integer` or pack the `Enum a` constraint into the type - from the point of view of a user of your type, it doesn't make a difference. Again, the real issue is your type is an abstract type and it the `Data` and `Generic` instances which need to be changed.

Comment: @0xd34df00d Perhaps my comment "Foldable doesn't make sense" has mislead you... I meant it doesn't make sense *to the compiler*. Yes, it make sense semantically, but the goal is to convince the compiler you are correct. You could write `data BitSet c = BitSet Integer` because the `a` becomes redundant (from the compilers point of view), or you could write `data BitSet c a = BitSet Integer` if that `a` has semantic meaning to you, or you could write `data BitSet c a where BitSet :: Enum a => c -> BitSet c a` if you wish to use the `Enum` instance directly. It is up to you!

Comment: @user2407038 You mean like `data Enum a => BitSet c a = BitSet c`? I've heard that's a bad practice, and it requires carrying `Enum a` basically everywhere, while, say, `Eq` or `Monoid` instances don't need this constraint. And, anyway, datatype contexts break Generic derivation as well, which brings us to the second part: I'm not sure I follow why would it be breaking the abstraction? `Data.Set` is `Data` as well (though it's not `Generic`), for instance.

Comment: @user2407038 Thanks for the clarification! From what I know, only the third option (with GADTs) would work - the other two still suffer from the same issue of typechecker not knowing that `c` is `Enum c` for all instantiations of `BitSet` at the point of defining the `Foldable` instance. But then it brings us again to whether we need generics.

Comment: @0xd34df00d If you look at the [`Data (Set a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/src/Data-Set-Internal.html#line-345) instance, it is not the auto-derived one, it is hand written (so as to not allow the breaking of the abstraction). You can have a `Data` instance as well, but it *cannot* be the auto-derived one. And nowhere have I written a type with a datatype context. I mean exactly what I wrote, what you asked about - a GADT.

Comment: All this being said, even if you get your Foldable instance, you will not be able to get Functor, nor Traversable, with the same 'trick', which semantically make sense as well. It seems you want a library like [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) which is specifically designed to solve this problem. Note that `Set` has a `map` function, but it doesn't abide by Functor laws - likewise for your type. Luckily, (or maybe unluckily), Foldable is pretty much lawless (or at least nobody can agree on the laws), so you can do anything you want there.